# What events are triggered during drawing with stylus using InkCanvas WPF?

Tags: .net, wpf, events, drawing, inkcanvas

I need to know a timestamp of each styluspoint collected in stroke. For further analysis I need coordinates and time of each one of them.

Taking timestamp from events seems to be the most sensible solution. However, each time I have got more coordinates than timestamps. I tried StylusDown, StylusButtonDown and StylusMove events and have no idea why it's not enough.

Comment: How do you collect the coordinates? Could you post a minimal code example that shows the problem?

Comment: I've been basing on [this tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16579/Saving-Rebuilding-InkCanvas-Strokes) but I'm saving coordinates to text file: `var list = new List<string>(); foreach (var item in customStrokes.StrokeCollection) { foreach (var n in item) { list.Add(n.ToString()); } list.Add(""); } File.WriteAllLines(filename, list);`

Comment: I think the assumption that each point has a corresponding event is wrong. AFAIK from experience, the strokes collection contains an estimation/simplification/simulation of the actual input to make the strokes more fluid.

Comment: Okay.. Do you have any idea how I could get the time for each coordinate?

Comment: No through this API, what do you want to use the time for? Some kind of replay?

Comment: I probably need it for analysis in matlab, but I will try to do without it. Lastly, I will use winforms. 
Thank you for your help

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean HOW you were going to use it but WHAT FOR.

Comment: I need to save data in .ink file with coordinate x, y and time